# Should I edit a code in order to respect code conventions?

Tags: discussion, code-formatting

Apart from obvious cases such as a lack of indentation, should we edit a question to fix a code that does not respect a code convention? In Python for instance, we have a clear Style Guide (http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) and it might be distracting sometimes to read a code that does not respect it. In Java there are also code conventions (http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html) but in many language the only rule is to stick to one.

What should I do?

Comment: I'd probably do this on a case by case basis. If poor/non-existant indenting makes the code unreadable... i.e. you can't tell where the if then else clauses end then edit it to make it understandable and impose whatever conventions you're most comfortable with. If it's easy to understand anyway then why bother?

Comment: @RobertLongson It's easy to understand but when you read a language that have a strong style guide, it is very distracting for me.

Comment: I think you probably need to grit your teeth and leave it alone in such cases.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My gut instinct is "no" because....

- there's a possibility that such edits introduce new errors...
- ... or inadvertently *fix* the OP's problem
- they have the potential to create confusion for the OP ("Should I try this new, improved code? Will it solve my problem?" or "WHY DID YOU CHANGE MY QUESTION???????????")
- For suggested edits (when you have < 2k reputation), there is the danger of the community rejecting the edit because it  looks like it's fundamentally changing the question

I'd rather leave a comment pointing to the appropriate style guide.

Comment: That's also what I think and that's what I am currently doing. I wanted to know if there is a rule about it or not. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

You should edit the code only to make it more readable for everyone, this means adding missing code-formatting blocks or breaking lines too long to fit in code block.

If your concern are **egyptian brackets** or **yoda clauses** or something similar, the answer should be **no**. The fact that you are used to break code blocks or compare items in other way is not the reason for modifying someone's question.

For the simple reason:

Assume there's someone like you, only following the opposite convention. He will edit your edit. Edit wars about coding styles is the last thing we need here.

Comment: My concern is for languages with a well known coding style that should always be respected such as with Python. The code that motivated to ask was using `tab[ i ]` to access the i-th element of a list instead of `tab[i]`. This is distracting and "wrong" according to PEP-8.

Comment: Even if it is considered 'wrong' by the general Python community, they are more readable for some people. There are many multi-language programmers, that apply the same coding style to all the code they write, there are also companies that enforce custom coding standards. Wars over coding standards are simply not constructive.

Comment: "adding missing code blocks" sounds more like an answer than a good edit. And breaking lines may introduce new errors - or fix ones caused by missing space.

Comment: @Mołot I've meant the SE formatting code blocks.

Comment: Well, if it does not require introducing line breaks et cetera, should be OK.